# Matching numbers with or without a decimal point

Tags: regex

I've been trying for a while to find a regular expression that I need.
3 characters before . and two characters after the decimal point.

I try this

```
[+ -]?[0-9]{0,3}[.]?[0-9]{0,2}    # but accepted as 55555 or the 
[+ -]?[0-9]{0,3}[.][0-9]{0,2}     # but this is not accepted as the 44
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: So, do you want at most three digits, then an optional "decimal point followed by at most two digits"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[+ -]?[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

[See it live](http://regexr.com?32vcg)

I added anchors at the beginning and end. If these are ommitted 55555 produces two matches: 555 and 55.

Comment: Thanx it is what i have looking for

Answer (score 4):

`55555` was matched in your first attempt because you made only the decimal point optional and `44` wasn't matched in your second because you only made the decimal point not optional. What you want to do is make the decimal place and the following digits all optional.

You also need to anchor the match otherwise `123`, `45.12` and `345` will match in `12345.12345` for example.

If you want to validate the string use this: `^[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Explanation:

```
^                # Match the start of string
[-+]?            # Optional plus or minus
[0-9]{1,3}       # Followed by 1 - 3 digits 
(\.[0-9]{1,2})?  # Optionally followed by decimal place (escaped \) & 1-2 digits 
$                # Match the end of the string
```

Try it out [here!](http://rubular.com/r/6Webl259eS)

*Further notes:*

This will only match strings that fit the pattern i.e. `123.34`

If you want to match the pattern inside a string i.e. `I am 123.34 cm tall`

Than use `(^|\s)` and `(\s|$)` as anchors instead:

```
(^|\s)[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?(\s|$)
```

Which matches the `^` start of line `|` any whitespace `\s`, the same with the end of the line `$`. The match will include the spaces so remember to `trim(match)` to removed them if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:-

```
 ^?[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9][0-9]?)?
```

or

```
 \d+(\.\d{1,2})?
```